# imagepng Very Slow

Tags: php

I have a .php file that's supposed to load an image for display in an img tag
(i.e., `<img src="the_file.php?which=0"/>`).  It looks like this:

```
<?php
    ob_clean();

    header("Content-type: image/png");

    include_once("util.php");

    //Do a simple calculation to get $name from (int)$_GET["which"];

    $im = imagecreatefrompng("protected_directory/".$name.".png");

    imagepng($im,NULL,0,NULL);

    imagedestroy($im);

    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

It works correctly, but the image loads substantially slower than just loading it directly
(i.e. `<img src="protected_directory/the_name.png"/>`, where "the_name" was calculated the same way as in the PHP file, but I can't just do this because the protected_directory isn't world readable).

My question is, why is this suddenly so much slower?  It's not a large image, but nor is it terribly small.

Comment: The problem still occurs when removing the include_once, and changing the simple calculation line (which uses it) to just $name="something";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just displaying an existing file, use `readfile()` to output it to the browser. There's no need to go through all the overhead of creating an editable GD object for this.

Comment: **+1** - That is the best method for existing files.

Answer (score 1):

`imagepng` [is known to be slow](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php#103787), if you need to output images with a PHP script, use code like this:

```
$filename = md5(time() . mk_rand());
imagepng($im, $filename);
echo file_get_contents($filename);
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of making a whole bunch of cache files willynilly for every page access (I think that's what this does; not sure).  But honorable mention; it lead me to fpassthru, which also works.  Thanks,

Comment: You are right, it does generate cache files. This is the method I use when making images *from scratch* with PHP, not for reading images (@ceejayoz answer is the best for this). Also, I forgot `unlink($filename);`.

Answer (score 1):

As another answer, I figured out that you can use the third parameter to compress the image (PNG uses zlib).  Setting it to 9 works about as well as the other solutions.

Comment: This depends on the speed at which the browser downloads the file. Setting it to `0` makes it faster to generate the image, but the file size will be larger (so it may take longer to download). Setting it to `9` will make it slower to generate, but it will download faster.

Comment: Right, because the server compresses it (and the client must decompress it).  Trades computing power for bandwidth.

Comment: Yes. If, for instance, some of your users are still on dial-up, compressing it heaps server-side will make it visibly faster.